# Android, Working on GPS but I don't know how real world coordinates work

Tags: android, gps

I want to find angle between two coordinates with latitude and longitude on the World, but i really don't know how it works because World is a globe and i am not sure if simple arctan(dy/dx) works. Should i think it as a 2D plane or what ? Will i get accurate results using simple arctan between two world coordinates ?

Comment: This may be off topic. Do you have any code that you are having problems with?

Comment: @gobernador, This is not off-topic at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the coordinates to 2 [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) objects, and use the [bearingTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) method. you'll receive the angle as a float.

Answer (score 1):

i am not exactly sure what you wanna calculate, because with latitude and logitude you just get a point on the globe.

or do you want the angle of the intersection between the circle of latitude, circle of longitude?

You can read in the WGS84 (World Geodetic System 1984) how to get from geodetic coordinates to  any other, if you give me a little bit more input i can help you with your data.

regards

Comment: I have some world coordinates in my database and according to my current world coordinates gathered by GPS, it will pick nearest point and tell the angle and distance between.

Comment: Okay, then you're cylinder-projection, which is normal. I don't know if it's usefull for you, in a cylinder-projection a direct line from one point to another isn't the shortest way to go on the earth.